# Отключить вывод некоторых логов в консоль

Tags: java, java-ee, slf4j, logback, logstash

Имеется Spring Boot приложение, запущенное в docker-контейнере. Логирование настроено с помощью slf4j + logback. Логи приложения записываются в Logstash и одновременно с этим, выводятся на консоль контейнера.
Возможно ли выключить только консольный вывод для конкретных классов? Например com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.HealthMonitor пишет:

```
2018-12-26 08:59:39.068  INFO 1 --- [s.HealthMonitor] c.h.internal.diagnostics.HealthMonitor   :  
processors=6, physical.memory.total=17.5G, physical.memory.free=1.8G, swap.space.total=7.9G, 
swap.space.free=4.7G, heap.memory.used=586.6M, heap.memory.free=1.4G, heap.memory.total=2.0G, 
heap.memory.max=2.0G, heap.memory.used/total=29.21%, heap.memory.used/max=29.21%, minor.gc.count=26,
...
```

Хотелось бы оставить запись таких логов в Logstash, но отключить для консольного вывода.

Текущая конфигурация logback-spring.xml содержит:

```
...

<configuration scan="true">
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>

    <appender name="LOGSTASH" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SocketAppender">
        <remoteHost>host</remoteHost>
        <port>port</port>
        <reconnectionDelay>10000</reconnectionDelay>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.HealthMonitor" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="LOGSTASH"/>
    </logger>
...
</configuration>
```

Однако в консоль логи все равно выводятся

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил следующим образом:

Заменил импорт `base.xml` на `default.xml` и сделал свой appender с фильтром для нужного класса
    ...

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <filter class="ru.package.name.HealthMonitorFilter" />
    <encoder>
        <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
...
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

HealthMonitorFilter.java:

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.core.filter.AbstractMatcherFilter;
import ch.qos.logback.core.spi.FilterReply;

public class HealthMonitorFilter extends AbstractMatcherFilter {
    @Override
    public FilterReply decide(Object event) {
        LoggingEvent loggingEvent = (LoggingEvent) event;
        if (loggingEvent.getLoggerName().contains("internal.diagnostics.HealthMonitor")) {
            return FilterReply.DENY;
        } else {
            return FilterReply.NEUTRAL;
        }
    }
}
```